# PHP if session equals mysql table row, do something

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've made a blog that prints all the posts from a single table named BlogData, the problem is that I want to be able to edit only the posts that I've posted, so I have stored in the column "poster" the name of the username that made the post.

```
 <div class="container">
 <?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BlogData ORDER BY id DESC");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
$category = $row['category'];
$image = $row['id'];
$extension= $row['ext'];
$title_color = $row['title_color'];
$content_color = $row['content_color'];
$category_color = $row['category_color'];
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$poster = $row['poster'];  // THIS IS WHERE THE USERNAME IS STORED
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ?>
 <hr />
 <div class="title" style=color:#<? echo $title_color ?>>
 <?php echo $title; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="date" style=color:#<? echo $category_color ?>>
 <?php echo $category; ?>
 <div class="poster" style=color:#<? echo $poster_color ?>>
 <?php echo $poster; ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php 
 echo "<img width='1140' height='300' src='uploads/".$image.".".$extension."'>";
  ?>
 <br>
 <div class="content" style=color:#<? echo $content_color ?>>
 <?php echo $content; ?>
 </div>
 <br>
 ////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////problem here
 ////////////////////////////////
 <?php
 if ($_SESSION['name'] == $row['poster']){
 echo "1";
 } else {
 echo "2";
 }
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

the problem is, the "echo" on the end of the code, is printing 1 on all posts that have something stored on the row "poster" and 2 on all the posts that the row "poster" is empty, it should print 1 only on the posts that I've created. how can this be solved?

Comment: where is the value of `$_SESSION['name']` is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
session_start();
```

In your pup code before reading the $_SESSION variable.

[PHP session_start manual](http://php.net/manual/it/function.session-start.php)

You could try to change your IF statement in this way, too:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'])
```

Comment: I have this command on the top of the page, do I need to put it again? still same problem

Comment: I can't see it in your posted code. If it is at the beginning it is ok. What happens if you echo $_SESSION[name]?

Comment: echoed $_SESSION[name] on if and else, and both printed "1"

Comment: I think you have to review the page in which you save the $_SESSION['name'] variable.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RgkDCJen and it stores exaclty the user that is logged in/posting...

Comment: its working this way: http://pastebin.com/MzrxWdHG but the EDIT button is on the middle of the date.... how to move it?